# Appium: Connect to 127.0.0.1:4723 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect

Tags: java, android, selenium, automation, appium

I am trying to write my first Java Appium test.
Each time I'm running my code the following errors are presented:

```
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:4723 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect  
....  
at MyFirstTest.setupTest(MyFirstTest.java:52)  
Caused by: org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connect to 127.0.0.1:4723 [/127.0.0.1] failed: Connection refused: connect  
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:158)  
at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:353)
```

Here is my code:

```
public class MyFirstTest  
{  
    public AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver;  
    public WebDriverWait wait;  
    String usersEmail = "xxxx@gmail.com";  
    String userPassword = "aaaaaa";  

    public void login() throws InterruptedException  
    {  
        WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[contains(@text,'Enter Email')]"));  
        email.sendKeys(usersEmail);  
        Sleeper.SYSTEM_SLEEPER.sleep(new Duration(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));  
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.RelativeLayout[contains(@resource-id,'edtPassword')]//android.widget.EditText[contains(@resource-id,'edtText')]")).sendKeys(userPassword);  
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[contains(@resource-id,'btnLogin')]")).click();  
    }  
    @Before  
    public void setupTest() throws Exception  
    {  
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();  
        capabilities.setCapability("platormName", "Android");  
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Redmi");  
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage","com.ls.stockpair");  
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.ls.stockpair.activity.SplashActivity");  
        driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);  
        Thread.sleep(8000);  
    }  
    @Test  
    public void go() throws InterruptedException  
    {  

    WebElement email = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[contains(@text,'Enter Email')]"));  
    email.sendKeys(usersEmail);  
    Sleeper.SYSTEM_SLEEPER.sleep(new Duration(1000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));  
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.RelativeLayout[contains(@resource-id,'edtPassword')]//android.widget.EditText[contains(@resource-id,'edtText')]")).sendKeys(userPassword);  
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.Button[contains(@resource-id,'btnLogin')]")).click();  

    Sleeper.SYSTEM_SLEEPER.sleep(new Duration(2000, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS));  
        }  
}
```

Currently I'm starting Appium manually before running the code. Also tried to start Appium from the code - this did not help.
This code worked in the first day I started writing this code however somehow (I really do not know why) this stopped working.
I saw many questions with different answers about this issue in the web but no one helped me so far.
I'm working with a real Android device connected via USB to my Windows machine.

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is localhost, meaning you're trying to connect to your Android device from your Android device, instead of to your Windows PC. You need to find the IP of your windows machine (start -> cmd -> ipconfig) and connect to that, instead. Also make sure your Android is connected to the same network, otherwise you'll have to expose the ports in your router.

Comment: What network are you talking about? The Android device is connected to the PC via USB. This code is appearing in all the online tutorials as a first Appium code. 127.0.0.1:4723 is the default Appium server address and port.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below is the best solution, You don't need to start appium manually everytime.

```
public static AndroidDriver<MobileElement> driver=null;
    public static AppiumDriverLocalService service=null;

    service = AppiumDriverLocalService.buildDefaultService();
    DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();  
    capabilities.setCapability("platormName", "Android");  
    capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Redmi");  
    capabilities.setCapability("appPackage","com.ls.stockpair");  
    capabilities.setCapability("appActivity","com.ls.stockpair.activity.SplashActivity");  

    service.start();
    driver = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(service, capabilities);
```

**Note : If you are using appium version 1.5.3+ then you need to set APPIUM_BINARY_PATH in environmental variable.**

e.g. APPIUM_BINARY_PATH=C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\appium\build\lib\main.js

For more details on how to set APPIUM_BINARY_PATH please refer below screen shot:

[image: APPIUM_BINRAYPATH]

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer!
Currently I'm too busy with some more urgent project on my work but I will  try this as soon as I can

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay, it was an urgent delay.
I'm using 1.4.16.1 Appium version and it says there is no updates. I see much higher versions on github but it's not executable file, no idea how to install it from there. But lets talk about the problem itself.
First let's make my code working with manually started Appium and after that will make Appium started from the code.

Comment: I tried to use your code. Received the following error: "io.appium.java_client.service.local.InvalidServerInstanceException: Invalid server instance exception has occured: There is no installed nodes! Please install node via NPM or download and install Appium app"

Comment: @Eliyahu after installing nodejs on your machine, did you set npm installation path to your environmental variables? if not please set. And if the issue remains then copy the path of main.js from the appium folder from npm directory and append the path to Path variable in environmental variable, it should work.

Comment: I did not. What variable is it? What is npm and what is it for?
Now I can start Appium programmatically but it stops and the process is aborted..

Comment: And how can I use the latest versions of Appium downloaded from github? These are not executable files. I can open archive, but not to install the files...

Comment: @Eliyahu npm is Node Package Manager. appium comes as package. To install npm through command line below is command : npm install -g appium

Comment: @Vinod,

What if we trying to connect 2 devices in parallel? I'm getting the exception while running 3 devices in parallel, the first device working well but the second refuses connection after opening the app.